# How do I put an arrow at an arbitrary point in the diagram in Drawio

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am drawing a diagram in Drawio but I cannot make the arrows behave well; they always snap to the background container or to one corner of the thing they connect to.

I need two arrows to arrive to the side of a component and they need to be separated, not centered and just stay there. If I move the component I'd rather move the arrows manually.

But it is impossible; either they stick to the middle of the side of a component or they stick to the background box that contains the two things I am connecting.[image: I selected the arrow and it will stick to the blue container, but I need it to be just a little above the other arrow that is going to the left object]

It's driving me crazy.

Comment: It's the bottom container that causes the issue. Removing it allows arbitrary positioning of the arrows.

Answer (score 2):

you could try the following: start dragging the arrow, hold Alt and drop it where you like. Alt+drag should avoid snapping.

If this doesn't help, tell me draw.io version you are using, browser version and attach the diagram file (if possible) so it can be tested.

Comment: Thanks, but in the end I noticed that it was the bottom container that was the problem; as long as it was present, I could not drag precisely. Using alt + didn't work for me, although I am on a mac so I tried control, command and option and none worked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it works for an image !